# Why did the Dregs leave Benni alive?

Tags: doctor-who

In S12E3, when the Dregs (giant mutated killing machines) take Benni, they carry him with them and leave him alive a long time, long enough to say his farewells to his partner when the Dregs are outside the vehicle (which the Dregs let him do). This must be at least 20 minutes later.

This is contrary to their modus operandi with other people, which is to kill them as fast as possible, as we saw with the other guests and resort employees. The only other exception is when the Doctor threatens the head Dreg into letting them walk out. One character speculates that the Dregs want to toy with him, but that seems unconvincing given their lack of interest in doing so either before or after.

So why did they keep him alive so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laura Fraser explains this to the Dr when she asks why they kept him alive after Kane killed him.

Not 100% on the line but pretty sure it was something like

"They where having fun"

and also

"He wanted to die, it was the best thing for him"

So the suggestion is that the oxygen kept them alive meaning that they could torture him longer as opposed to normal humans who die before the Dreggs can have much fun.

Comment: +1. This is the answer that is based on the script rather than surmise. It was also borne out in the episode that the Dreggs were far more intelligent than at first assessment, as The Doctor spoke to the one she trapped and believed it would understand her, and this would support the idea that they might 'toy' with their prey.

Answer (score 1):

Benny is using an oxygen tank to assist his respiration, and we later see that the Dregs are averse to oxygen. It seems the Dregs avoided Benny to some degree until his oxygen ran out.

You could ask why the Dregs didn't avoid the other people using the emergency oxygen devices. I can only surmise that the "nasal clip" design of the emergency services leak less oxygen to the environment than the more traditional nasal flow tube that Benni is using, and so the Dregs don't have the same aversion.

Comment: They were carrying him with them, though. And not killing him.